# Run a remote desktop connection from linux (ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a little problem that is troubling me. Can i connect to a windows trough remote desktop protocol from a linux (Ubuntu)?

In Windows i have **Remote Desktop Connection**

http://www.techotopia.com/images/8/81/Windows_server_2008_remote_desktop_connection.jpg

but in linux i can connect only to other linux.

And i don't know if is possible. Is this possible?

Thank you

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com), [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com), or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are bare-boned applications like `rdesktop` as well as a number of nicer ones that can set up configuration defaults etc.  The way it goes with KDE and Gnome, these apps sometimes go stale, get replaced, have inconsistent naming etc but hey, the price is right.

I currently like [**remmina**](http://remmina.sourceforge.net/) the best. It is a Gnome/Gtk+ plus application. One nice feature is that it also has [**NX**](http://www.nomachine.com) plugins and more.  All works out of the box on my Ubuntu systems.

Answer (score 1):

I always use this **optimal configuration simply running rdesktop from terminal**:

```
$ rdesktop -u REMOTE_USER -p REMOTE_PASSWORD -k pt -g 1440x900 -T "MY REMOTE SERVER" -N -a 16 -z -xl -r clipboard:CLIPBOARD -r disk:SHARE_NAME_ON_REMOTE=LOCAL_SHARED_FOLDER_PATH SERVER_HOSTNAME_OR_IP_ADDRESS
```

This includes defining the **desired window size** (-k pt, choose the desired one for you), adding a **meaningful window title** (-T "MY REMOTE SERVER") , enabling **clipboard support** (-r clipboard:CLIPBOARD) and a **shared folder** ( disk:SHARE_NAME_ON_REMOTE=LOCAL_SHARED_FOLDER_PATH) between your Linux host and Windows host.

Additionally you can also create a bash script each connection that you use more often:

```
#!/bin/sh

rdesktop \
    -u REMOTE_USER \
    -p REMOTE_PASSWORD \
    -k pt \
    -g 1440x900 \
    -T "MY REMOTE SERVER" \
    -N \
    -a 16 \
    -z \
    -xl \
    -r clipboard:CLIPBOARD \
    -r disk:SHARE_NAME_ON_REMOTE=LOCAL_SHARED_FOLDER_PATH \
    SERVER_HOSTNAME_OR_IP_ADDRESS
```

Comment: good answer :) i wonder, can i send commands or take a snapshot ?

Comment: Haven't tried but there is a -s (Shell) switch that, according to the documentation, allows to start a specific application.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, there are apps like Remote Desktop Viewer that are capable of use the RDP (remote desktop protocol)

Comment: Connecting from Linux to a Windows

Comment: Yes. Linux TO Windows.  if you're using Ubuntu, you can get the Remote Desktop View via that crap Unity app finder.

Answer (score -2):

If you have an UI based linux you can install applications like Remmina to access the RDP. If you are using a ssh then it is possible to get UI for the linux using xrdp and then you can use external tools mentioned (like Remmina) to access the windows machine.

Comment: And this improves on the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9120107/1394729) how exactly?